# How can I make tabs permanent after quick open in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

In Xcode, when I use `Cmd+Shift+O` (Quick open) to open a file, it creates a temporary tab. Then, I have to double click to make it permanent. I've googled around for a bit, but couldn't find any way to make the tabs permanent by default.

Do any of you know if this is possible? If so, where would I change this setting?

Currently using XCode 12.5

Comment: It seems that the option is not exposed in the UI (I would expect though the presence of a flag in the Xcode defaults). Another shortcut that may ease the process is `Command + Option + O` as a replacement for double-click.

Comment: @Alladinian Hmm, ok. Do you know if there's any manual way I can toggle that flag (though a config file or something)?

Comment: 3 years later this still doesn't work as expected. Though it's XCode, we should be happy the tabs even open in the first place, even if they immediately close the tab you already had open. Only Apple can struggle this hard to make a code editor.

Comment: I have to agree... This is one the most infuriating things about XCode navigation...

Answer (score 1):

I have found a small workaround for this. I use keyboard for the navigation, mostly with Vim bindings, so using a mouse for that was infuriating.

It turns out you can use `Cmd+Shift+o` and then press `Option+Enter` to modify the way XCode opens the file. The default is to open the file in a separate editor, not a new tab, but you can customize this behaviour in XCode settings. Here is a screenshot of the settings that allow to use `Option+Enter` to open the file in a new tab instead of replacing the temporary tab with the opened file. The crucial setting is `Optional Navigation`. If you set this to `Uses Tab` and then use `Option+Enter` instead of just `Enter` to choose the file from the `Quick Open` list, XCode will open the file in a new tab, no matter if you have an already opened temporary tab (temporary indicated by its name in italics).

[image: XCode settings set up for files to open in a new tab when pressing Option+Enter]

Comment: this is so much better!!! Thank you